# Bullet points are not recognized in HTML String

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a string:

```
NSString *str1 = @"\u2022 You were held in custody for a longer 
                   period of time than may have been necessary.";
```

I am converting it into an HTML string using this code :

```
- (NSString *)HTMLString {
    NSDictionary * const exportParams = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
    NSAttributedString *attributed = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str1];
    NSData *htmlData = [attributed dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributed.length) documentAttributes:exportParams error:nil];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

But bullet points are not showing in the HTML string. It's showing a `?` instead of bullet point. Please tell me any solution.

Comment: Your code is working fine in my test sample. Please show some code where you have used this string for web view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code -

```
- (NSString *)HTMLString {
    NSDictionary * const exportParams = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
    letterString = [letterString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u2022" withString:@"•"];
    NSAttributedString *attributed = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:letterString];
    NSData *htmlData = [attributed dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributed.length) documentAttributes:exportParams error:nil];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: Actually i want to show this string as a text body of a mail , So  i want to show bullet points on mail body ( not BULLET_POINT).

Comment: Yes BULLET_POINT replace by "•"

Comment: thanks bro its working and i replace "•" with "*" because "•" was also not recognized .